# Brother HL-1110e printer driver

Tags: drivers, brother

Could you please help me with installation of printer Brother HL-1110e for Kubuntu 14.04? I haven't found any official driver. Someone did [package for Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177290), I converted them with [`alien`](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien) to `.deb`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the official driver from brother website:
http://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1110_us_eu_as

Comment: It would be useful to include which one of three options is a proper driver (website is not explaining well differences between available downloads)

Answer (score 1):

For me instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html added printer but it refused to work properly (printer failed to leave any toner on pages) - maybe it was caused by missing option for HL 1110 drivers and recognizing printer as HL 1070.

Going to http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1110_us_eu_as selecting download, selecting deb version, downloading "Driver Install Tool", lying that I read and agree to EULA and following:

- Step 1: Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)

  The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
  (The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
  e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download
- Step 2: Open a terminal window.
- Step 3: Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step. By using the `cd` command.

  e.g. `cd Downloads`
- Step 4: Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

  Command: `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz`

  e.g. `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz`
- Step 5: Get superuser authorization with the `su` command or `sudo su` command.
- Step 6: Run the tool:

  Command: `bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name`
  e.g. `bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J880DW`
- Step 7: The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

  When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

  For USB Users: Choose N(No)
  For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI number.

  The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

This printer is a shit.

Is support a very few amount of buffer.

https://openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-HL-1110